# "Папа видел, что сын старается побороть свою лень и нерадение,— и решил поощрить его". Функция тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

Какова функция тире в данном предложении (правило)? И факультативно ли оно здесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире факультативно, его можно объяснить присоединением:

Если во второй части сложносочиненного предложения содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление, то между ними перед союзом вместо запятой ставится тире: *Оковы тяжкие падут, темницы рухнут — и свобода вас примет радостно у входа (П.); Тут раздался лёгкий свист — и Дубровский умолк (П.); Я спешу туда ж — а там уже весь город (П.); Все вскочили, схватились за ружья — и пошла потеха (Л.); Но вот опять хлынули играющие лучи — и весело и величаво поднимается могучее светило (Т.); Вавила бросил что-то в костёр, притоптал — и тотчас же стало очень темно* (Ч.).

Answer (score 1):

*Видел* и *решил*  — сказуемые. Грамота говорит ([§ 169](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire)), что тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому, например: 
Я вышел, не желая его обидеть, на террасу – и обомлел.

Я не вижу ни неожиданного присоединения, ни резкого противопоставления, поэтому не ставил бы тире. Но возможно, в контексте есть что-то такое, что позволяет считать решение отца неожиданным?

Answer (score 1):

**Авторское тире**: подчеркивается **пауза** между сказуемыми, ослабляется связь между ними.  Конструкция приближается к ССП   (...и (он) решил поощрить его).

Официально объясняется присоединительным характером союза (тоже как авторское решение).

Answer (score 1):

1. Функция тире тут в интонационной паузе, оно пишется/не пишется в зависимости от того, как автор считает должным почувстовать текст: резко или плавно.

   > … лежал на поляне в покое и — уснул.

И всё же его употребление факультативно.